# How can I get a SingleOrDefault value from a one to many join with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-identity

I have two classes that are used by ASP.NET Identity. One is the backing class for a list of users and the other has roles. In the database there are three tables. AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles. Because of the way they are mapped in Entity Framework these three are mapped to just two classes:

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        this.AspNetUserClaims = new List<AspNetUserClaim>();
        this.AspNetUserLogins = new List<AspNetUserLogin>();
        this.AspNetRoles = new List<AspNetRole>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class AspNetRole
{
    public AspNetRole()
    {
        this.AspNetUsers = new List<AspNetUser>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
```

I have this LINQ statement I am using to do a report of the data. Note that I just want to get the first of the roles that is associated with the user. Here's what I tried:

```
        var user = await db.AspNetUsers
            .Where(u => u.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Id == roleId) || roleId == 0)
            .Include(u => u.AspNetRoles)
            .Select(u => new UserDTO
            {
                Email = u.Email,
                RoleSingleId = u.AspNetRoles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id),
                UserId = u.Id,
                UserName = u.UserName
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

But this gives me two errors with a blue line under r.Id

Error   4   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types 
in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Error   5   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'  C:\App\ab41\Admin1\WebRole1\Controllers\Web API - Data\UserController.cs    169 71  WebRole1

Note RoleSingleId is declared as an int and the Id from AspNetRoles is also an int.

Comment: As posted, you're missing a closing paren on the `.Where` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems. Let's start with the one that gives the compile-time errors.

> ```
> RoleSingleId = u.AspNetRoles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id),
> ```

[`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549274%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) takes a predicate, not a projection. What you pass as a parameter is a condition that tells whether the specified `AspNetRole` should be considered. It's short for `u.AspNetRoles.Where(r => r.Id).SingleOrDefault()`.

That isn't what you want. Projection is done with `Select`, not with `Where`, so that part could be fixed by writing it as `u.AspNetRoles.Select(r => r.Id).SingleOrDefault()`.

Once you've fixed that, the next problem is that `SingleOrDefault()` is designed to throw an exception if multiple items are found. That's not what you want. You say you want one of those role IDs to be returned. There's `FirstOrDefault()` for that.

A third problem that's neatly sidestepped is that `SingleOrDefault()` often simply is not supported in queries. It will compile, but it will throw an exception at run-time regardless of how many roles the user has, telling you that it just does not understand how to do that, and that you may want to use `FirstOrDefault()` instead. Since `FirstOrDefault()` is what you should be using anyway, that's not a problem.

Note: you may also want to change `Select(r => r.Id)` to `Select(r => (int?)r.Id)`: the former returns `IEnumerable<int>`, the latter returns `IEnumerable<int?>`. `FirstOrDefault()` would then return `0` for the former if the user has no roles (if it works at all), and `null` for the latter. `null` probably makes more sense here. You would need to adjust the type of `RoleSingleId` the same way.

Comment: *SingleOrDefault() often simply is not supported in queries*: do you have a concrete example of an EF provider that does not support `SingleOrDefault`?

Answer (score 2):

If you use SelectMany instead of Select, then your return will be flattened much like a traditional SQL statement.  i.e. The user details will be repeated per role for that user.

Getting Single or Default user/role will look something like this:

```
var user = await db.AspNetUsers
        .Where(u => u.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Id == roleId) || roleId == 0)
        .Include(u => u.AspNetRoles)
        .SelectMany(u => new UserDTO
        {
            Email = u.Email,
            RoleSingleId = u.AspNetRoles.Id,
            UserId = u.Id,
            UserName = u.UserName
        })
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

Of course, if you're trying to get a list of first role against each user, then you'll need to GroupBy user ID, Username and e-mail, aggregating role ID in some way (such as taking the maximum value per user).

i.e.

```
var user = await db.AspNetUsers
        .Where(u => u.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Id == roleId) || roleId == 0)
        .Include(u => u.AspNetRoles)
        .SelectMany(u => new UserDTO
        {
            Email = u.Email,
            RoleSingleId = u.AspNetRoles.Id,
            UserId = u.Id,
            UserName = u.UserName
        })
        .GroupBy(key => new { key.Email, key.UserId, key.UserName },
        (key, agg) => new UserDTO 
            {
                Email = key.Email,
                UserId = key.Id,
                UserName = key.UserName,
                RoleSingleId = agg.Max(a => a.RoleSingleId),
            })
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks but will this just show one user or many? I want to show many users with just the first role for each.

Comment: Edited to answer.  You can probably make the LINQ tidier, but you get the idea :)